# Google Dataflow pipeline stuck on shuffeling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Yesterday I started a Job on Google-Dataflow which usually runs about 10-30min. It was still running this morning. When looking into stackdriver, I saw one repeating loop of logs for the job:

```
I  Refused to split GroupingShuffleReader <at position ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVgAAQ) of shuffle range [ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAAD_AP8A_wD_AAE), ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVkAAQ))> at ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVkAAQ) 
E  Refusing to split <at position ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVgAAQ) of shuffle range [ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAAD_AP8A_wD_AAE), ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVkAAQ))> at ShufflePosition(base64:AAAABOA3nVkAAQ): proposed split position out of range 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit our-project-id;2017-09-26_09_29_26-14666853265610614017;1268593085087986642 at {"fractionConsumed":1.0,"position":{"shufflePosition":"AAAABOA3nVkAAQ"}} 
I  Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
```

I now cancelled the job. Before this job started, I reduced the disksize for workers to 40GB, because our quota of 10,240GB(!!!) was exceeded with about 15 Jobs. I will increase the disksize to around 100GB, but more shouldn't be necessary.

Any suggestions on how to fix this otherwise or how this can happen? It would also be interesting what this error really means...

The JobID: 2017-09-26_09_29_26-14666853265610614017

[image]

The Step "ToElasticsearch" Was showing 16hours before I cancelled the job. In this step, there are only http-Posts for each article to Elasticsearch

Comment: I looked at this job and it seemed stuck forever on a single record in the ToElasticsearch step - it seems like your user code is doing something that takes forever, e.g. is doing an infinite retry loop over a failing HTTP request, or something like that. You might want to add some logging to your ToElasticsearch step to debug the problem.

Comment: (The logging you're seeing is part of normal operation and unrelated to the issue - I agree that it's confusing, especially the message logged at ERROR level)

Comment: If you are using a 2.1.0 SDK or newer, you should be able to find these stuck elements by searching the logs for the phrase "Processing lull".

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that you have a hot-key. Specifically, one of the keys produces the majority of the output. In such a case, the work doesn't distribute across the available workers well. You could try inserting a `Reshuffle` transform after the steps that may have many outputs for a single input. It sounds like doing so after the ReadArticlesFromDatastore step may be the right place.

Comment: In general this is good advice, but in this case it's not a hot key but it's a single stuck value.